# What could I have done to get the expertise needed for this PHP question?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

I am having trouble getting a complete answer for my question [ob_start not working in PHP 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917293/ob-start-not-working-in-php-5-5)

Now forget the title and read the actual question; you soon realise this question is about functionality that has changed since PHP 5.3 and 5.5 under the same `error_reporting` etc etc.

Unfortunately the highest rated and seemingly best community-voted answer I got was a one-liner explaining where to put my `headers();` (check question edit history). Not even the answer I attached a bounty to, which seemed to be the only one which understood the question, really gave me a decent enough solution; it was a wild guess feeling at best.

After some time I tried to edit my question to use `headers_sent()` and be more specific instead, but it didn't seem to change anything.

I have also tried a bounty, as you can see.

So what could I have done to get the expertise and eyes, and for those eyes to take this seriously, on this question?

Comment: After reading your question and the bountied answer I am not sure what part of "why is my live server returning true? What has changed since 5.3 to cause this?" remains unanswered. If there is still a part of the question that is unanswered, make clear what part of the question is still unanswered. Besides that, I think you over-simplified the question.

Comment: @Sumurai8 which part answers it in your view?

Comment: The first question: CLI got a webserver variant, which means it must do something with headers. Which means it works the same as 'normal' php. Which means it gets sent when the first output is being buffered ("lalalalala"). The adding of a webserver to cli mode and the subsequent change to headers in cli is what changed in 5.3.

Comment: @Sumurai8 ah ok, the problem I (as the OP) see with that answer is 0 references etc etc. It is basically someone without any referenceable authority saying PHP works this way in my view as the OP. You can see by my first comment that I actually throw a spanner by saying it works in a browser

Comment: @Sumurai8 so you would say that the answer posted there answers it? That is interesting, would be interesting to know if many others would think that too

Answer (score 2):

I know really I am not supposed to mentor myself, it is kind of useless but I thought I would wtrite an example answer, so here goes.

I can immediately see some problems with the question.

Your title is very generic and simple, as @sumurai8 says, it may have over simplified the question. Many people will read by the title of a question and assume the content, you need a title that accurately, yet concisely, sums up your problem.

Maybe:

```
Why does this difference in ob_start exist between PHP 5.3 and 5.5?
```

This could have stopped a lot of people instantly assuming it was another "move the ob_start() over there" and could have got a lot better quality answers.

This, in fact, could have been the single biggest problem, most people will read by title and assume content based on the title. This is a trait that all internet users possess (as a person who develops sites such as retail sites I have to study these patterns for business).

The question also suffered 4 upvotes and 4 downvotes, this means that people either saw it as a bad question and skipped over it or again they assumed the content and left it. The 4th edit ( https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21917293/revisions ) shows that you originally use `header()` to prove your point which could have caused a lot of confusion and over-simplification of your real problem leading to not only the downvotes but also all but one answer not even being on topic to the question.

The revision history also shows that you had a lot of question to read through, this means that people skim read the large bits and didn't read the fine print. You need to make sure your question is just the right length. It is an okay length now but for a time it trailed off.

Judging by this comment: [ob_start not working in PHP 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917293/ob-start-not-working-in-php-5-5#comment33196219_21917373) here you should have been explicit that both servers were running with `E_ALL` only for `error_reporting`. That would have made for a better reception and most likely avoided: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21917373/383478

As for the partially accepted answer: it is lacking references and authority as to its information, that is a given and even though in the first comment:[ob_start not working in PHP 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917293/ob-start-not-working-in-php-5-5#comment33302018_21975922) you do make him aware that the code works within a browser, there has been no clarification on his end. As such it is safe to say he disengaged from answering further or did not quite understand that even by the second comment you did not feel the answer was suitable as such no action was taken.

As such I agree with you on that, however, you could have spelled it out better by physically saying: "I cannot verify anything you say, please can you confirm your information?"

So the one answer that was on topic could have been handled better as well.

Those are some points that could have got you the answer you wanted.